# Paypal: How to keep custom var when recurring donation?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've a donation button on my site, but it gives the choice to donate every month...etc,
but when the recurring payment is done the custom var that was passed the first time do not exist anymore, and this custom var is crucial for my system.

I would like either keeping the custom var, or remove the recurring option from paypal donation page

Comment: Save it the first time you get it, along with the rest of the transaction, and look it up next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove the recurring feature from the donate button, you would need to go in step 2 of the button creation on PayPal and uncheck the box to save the button on PayPal. Then once you hit create button, click "remove code protection" above the HTML code. You can then add the following line of code to remove the recurring feature:

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0">
```